# Can I get the media loaded in an <audio> element as a blob (or ArrayBuffer)?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

I need to get the same media that is loaded in a HTML5 media player into an AudioContext. Can I somehow grab it from the media player (or do I have to download it again)?

Note: The media player does not have to be playing, but I know that all of the media has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same file, you'd need to fetch it again (using `fetch` or XHR), but if your server is well configured, you may not need to download it again no, it should be cached.

Note that if you need to *connect* your HTMLMediaElement to the AudioContext (so that its audio output goes through the AudioContext's graph), then you can use either [`HTMLMediaElement.captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream) + [`AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource), or [`AudioContext.createMediaElementSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource).

Comment: Thanks, I hoped I could extract it as a blob from html5 media player.